# How can you run Apple Diagnostic through an external monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My MacBook Pro A1708 is recovering from water damage.

From not working it has since been cleaned and have the LVDs Cable replaced.

Currently the display is showing black but I am able to connect to an external display.

If possible I would like to run Apple Diagnostics through an external monitor if anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps exactly:

- Start your computer with external screen plugged in and an external keyboard, typically a USB keyboard
- Once your screen is started, close its lid, it will go to sleep
- On your USB keyboard, type a key. It will wake up, but now using external display as its main display
- Instruct it to restart
- Hold D on external keyboard when it chimes

Answer (score 0):

The solution I eventually found was the following.

> Turn on Mac while HDMI is connected to External Monitor
>   Hold D till Mac is on
>   Close Mac Screen
>   Diagnostics will show on External Monitor

Hope this can be some assistance to you.

Comment: Can you add a link to the source for that quote?